# No more cursor movement (via keyboard) in Python3 interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, cursor

I recently compiled Python 3.3 from source and installed it in my home directory on a Linux Ubuntu workstation. Everything worked fine until I had to restart my computer today.

Usually, I could use the arrow keys on my keyboard to navigate in the command line of the Python3 interpreter (in a bash shell) - and it still works with the Python2.7 interpreter on this machine. Now, when I want to use the up-key to to access the history, or left or right to move the cursor in the command line, the interpreter does not recognize those as such, but inserts characters instead.
e.g.,

```
^[[D^[[A^[[B^[[C
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could fix this problem? It worked fine until the restart, something must have happened after that.

Comment: You could use ipython, it has this functionality and more...

Comment: I usually write my code in vi, but here and there I use the interpreter in the bash shell to try things out. I mean, it worked just fine before the restart, maybe I will just reinstall it tomorrow. I hear many positive things about iPython, but I don't want to install it on this workstation here. Though, trying it out at home on my Mac is very big on my To Do List

Comment: thanks, i will try it tomorrow when I am back at the work station. Btw what is "tty"?

Comment: `os.system('pmap %d | grep readline' % os.getpid())` returns `256`, I assume this means that readline is working?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what could have caused it to stop working after restart.
But you can try installing readline with pip or easy_install

Comment: I have to say that it is really weird, since the Python 2.7 works just fine. What is this readline doing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurs with the OS X package install of python 3.4. Installing readline allows the arrow keys to be used in the same way as in python 2.7.

$pip3 install readline

pip is built into python 3.4. If you have python2 on your system you may need to use "pip3" rather than "pip".